# React Hook "useCreateContext" cannot be called at the top level

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am writting an React landing page, but have an error below:

4:40  error  React Hook "useCreateContext" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Here is the code which may cause the problem.

```
import React, { useContext, createContext } from 'react';

export function useCreateContext(defaultValue, reducer) {
  const defaultDispatch = () => defaultValue;
  const stateCtx = createContext(defaultValue);
  const dispatchCtx = createContext(defaultDispatch);

  function useStateCtx(property) {
    const state = useContext(stateCtx);
    return state[property]; // only one depth selector for comparison
  }

  function useDispatchCtx() {
    return useContext(dispatchCtx);
  }

  function Provider({ children }) {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, defaultValue);
    return (
      <dispatchCtx.Provider value={dispatch}>
        <stateCtx.Provider value={state}>{children}</stateCtx.Provider>
      </dispatchCtx.Provider>
    );
  }
  return [useStateCtx, useDispatchCtx, Provider];
}


export const initialState = {
  isSticky: false,
  isSidebarSticky: true,
};

export function reducer(state, { type }) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'SET_STICKY':
      return {
        ...state,
        isSticky: true,
      };
    case 'REMOVE_STICKY':
      return {
        ...state,
        isSticky: false,
      };
    case 'SET_SIDEBAR_STICKY':
      return {
        ...state,
        isSidebarSticky: true,
      };
    case 'REMOVE_SIDEBAR_STICKY':
      return {
        ...state,
        isSidebarSticky: false,
      };
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported action type: ${type}`);
    }
  }
}

const [state, useDispatch, provider] = useCreateContext(initialState, reducer);

export const useStickyState = state;
export const useStickyDispatch = useDispatch;
export const StickyProvider = provider;
```

Then I use the StickProvider in the home page.

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <StickyProvider>
      <Layout>
        <SEO title="Startup Landing 005" />
        <Banner />
        <KeyFeature />
        <ServiceSection />
        <Feature />
        <CoreFeature />
        <WorkFlow />
        <Package />
        <TeamSection />
        <TestimonialCard />
        <BlogSection />
        <Subscribe />
      </Layout>
    </StickyProvider>
  );
}
```

Can anyone help with how to fix this error?

Comment: Thats not a hook so don't use the `use` prefix

Comment: I had a similar issue. This is what fixed it for me thanks @DennisVash

Answer (score 2):

you have to call this
const [state, useDispatch, provider] = useCreateContext(initialState, reducer);
inside the function not outside you are breaking hooks rule.
The way you are doing outside function it's wrong

Comment: Then, how to solve it? Please provide some code to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

You should rename useCreateContext to another not including "use" prefix because now is a reserved word in react, the same case with "set".